# What's the best way to resume an HTTP POST?

Tags: javascript, authentication, web-applications, oauth-2.0, saml-2.0

I am trying to handle following case, I am new to web-app world so please pardon my ignorance (if any):

Assumptions/Constraints:

1. I don't have any control over the web-app code base whatsoever.
2. Authentication is being handled at http proxy level.

Scenario:

1. User has authenticated with a web-app using SAML and has been accessing the web-app for quite some time.
2. His authentication token (or cookie) expires.
3. He submits a form (HTTP POST).
4. Server needs to perform the authentication workflow again, which requires a HTTP redirect.

Now, the requirement is to somehow resubmit the original HTTP POST, after completing the authentication workflow, automatically for the user. A couple of options I could think of are:

1. Use javascript injection to store the POST state in browser's sessionStorage and rePOST things after completing the auth workflow. But I couldn't figure how would this work if the original POST was done using XMLHttpRequest ???
2. Store POST state on server (or proxy) side and do an internal rePOST and return the result to the browser.

Are there any other options ??? It'd be great if we could avoid saving state on server side. How do people usually handle such scenarios?

TIA,

praddy

Answer (score 0):

Generally the second approach is implemented.

You send the request to the server running the application, it preserves the POST data (actually the again doing the authentication does this), sends you to authenticate, redirects you back and POSTs the data again. This feature may already be present in your authentication infrastructure and just needs to be enabled, but that of course depends what you are running.

This feature is sometimes also referred to 'POST data preservation'.